# Why does my bootstrap fluid carousel get so small when viewed between 771px and 993px wide

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-modal

When my modal based bootstrap carousel is viewed between 771px and 993px wide, it gets very small and has huge left and right margins.

At all other sizes, it reduces proportionally with just enough margin for the forward and background arrows.

Any insights as to why?

```js
/* activate the carousel */
$("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function(){
  $(".modal-title")
  .html($(this)
        .find(".active img")
        .attr("title"));
});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$(".row .thumbnail").click(function(){
  var content = $(".carousel-inner");
  var title = $(".modal-title");

  content.empty();  
  title.empty();

  var id = this.id;  
  var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
  var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
  var active = repoCopy.first();

  active.addClass("active");
  title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
  content.append(repoCopy);

  // show the modal //
  $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* modal full background opacity */
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* change opacity of modal border to match
modal background opacity */
.modal-content {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/* arrow style */
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
  background-image:none;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* arrow postition outside image */
.carousel {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- #image-1 (row of images) -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a title="Image 4">
      <a href="#" class="pop">  
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-4" src="images/powwow/powwow_04.jpg">
      </a>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="img-repo">

  <div class="item" id="image-1">
    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="" src="images/powwow/powwow_01.jpg">
  </div>     
</div>

<!-- modal carousel gallery -->   
<div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">           
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Gleb! That worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of the `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">` block. Let's explore [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css):

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 900px;
  }
}
```

So the width of this block becomes `600px` when the screen width is between `768px` and `991px`. But you can redefine this property by CSS. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```js
/* activate the carousel */
$("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function(){
  $(".modal-title")
  .html($(this)
        .find(".active img")
        .attr("title"));
});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$(".row .thumbnail").click(function(){
  var content = $(".carousel-inner");
  var title = $(".modal-title");

  content.empty();  
  title.empty();

  var id = this.id;  
  var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
  var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
  var active = repoCopy.first();

  active.addClass("active");
  title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
  content.append(repoCopy);

  // show the modal //
  $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

/* modal full background opacity */
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* change opacity of modal border to match
modal background opacity */
.modal-content {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/* arrow style */
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
  background-image:none;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* arrow postition outside image */
.carousel {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- #image-1 (row of images) -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a title="Image 4">
      <a href="#" class="pop">  
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-4" src="images/powwow/powwow_04.jpg">
      </a>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="img-repo">

  <div class="item" id="image-1">
    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="" src="images/powwow/powwow_01.jpg">
  </div>     
</div>

<!-- modal carousel gallery -->   
<div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">           
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```